# A "guide to maths" like Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request

On SO, there is a "Documentation" tab. I was thinking, what if there was a guide to mathematics on Maths SE?

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23684/11619)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, correct. However, I just can't be bothered anymore with checking because I just keep getting having a go at repeatedly for apparent "bad posts"

Comment: @Goodra: Asking a "duplicate" Question is not considered a "bad post".  In this case I'd encourage you, if you have some specific thoughts about how the Documentation model could apply to benefit Math.SE, to post an Answer or Comment on the earlier thread.  As you'll see there, one of the earlier Comments was to the effect of revisiting this issue in "six months", so it would be timely if you wanted to explain your ideas.